# How can I have Merlin look in other files when I have a multi-file OCaml project?

Tags: ocaml, atom-editor, merlin-project

Suppose I have two files, `foo.ml` and `bar.ml`. In `foo.ml` I type:

`open Bar;;`

Which will import the `bar.ml` file. Is there a way to have my Merlin Atom package look in that `bar.ml` file rather than telling me it is an unbound module?

Comment: which version of ocaml are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues you already read [this](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki/vim-from-scratch#configuring-your-project) .
In your example : write .merlin file

```
 S .

 B _build
```

Once this is done, you can benefit of the autocompletion to get the elements contained in Bar.

I am using Atom 1.41 & ocamlc 4.03 and completion runs fine in Atom (may be it is a matter of update of Atom - also: do you have all ocaml package installed ? merlin & ocp-index at least).